# Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate Ubuntu 18.0.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install WPS office and it depends on libpng12-0 which I can't install due to "Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate
". I'm running Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS.

Comment: You can use the Ubuntu 16.04 package, I guess http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ... I used an old Debian package http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.27-2+lenny5_amd64.deb ... ( I don't remember why.) Install : `sudo gdebi Downloads/libpng12*`

Comment: It fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I did not get any version of libpng12-0 under bionic packages but it is available under xenial packages. Just download it from the below link and install the file, it will solve your problem. https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download Choose any of the mirrors from the above link and it will start downloading. It is a .deb file so just double-clicking it will start installing process.

Comment: Try these below commands: Hope you will get success.

"sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12"
          
"sudo apt update"
       
"sudo apt install libpng12-0"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ... trying to install WPS office and it depends on libpng12-0

You can use the Ubuntu 16.04 package http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Download, and install ...

```
sudo gdebi Downloads/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404213/install-libpng12-on-ubuntu-22-04?noredirect=1&lq=1   this solved my "no installation candidatef for libpng12 " problem for ubuntu 22.04. get the source code and compile it!

Comment: ← user50619 : Old packages https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DUKKvui64R5gqVdhxYn-31y8HXmP8lxe ....... Download , and install libpng12 : `sudo apt install Downloads/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb` ........... Actually that's "the same" as my above answer ........

Comment: Similar, but I could not get the debian package to install on 22.04 ubuntu. So I eventually found this  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404213/install-libpng12-on-ubuntu-22-04?noredirect=1&lq=1 . Following the instructions there I managed to get a working libpng12 (well worked for fluid / fltk 1.3.8)